# Postgres, Sequelize and Express

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have been trying to connect my expressJS app with postgress using sequelize ORM but I can't get data or add directly to the database. I need connection help

Comment: Please post what error you are exactly facing

Answer (score 0):

Let's run through connecting Sequelize to the database.
Get psql command line tools and in the command line write:

```
createdb exampledb
```

To connect Sequelize to the currently running database process we use the following:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/exampledb');
```

Port number 5432 is the default. If there is an error connecting — for example, if your database process is not running — Sequelize will throw an error and your process will halt.